# I need to translate a phrase "From the bottom of my heart, to the root"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, translation-check, idiom, sentence-translation

The phrase is "From the bottom of my heart, to the root" I need it in Latin, I researched it and I found that the phrase is "Ab imo pectore ad radices", but I need to be sure.

Thanks for the help